# How To make own Template Inbox view use MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using SMTP for mail sending . now its  wokring normal mail  message  send to the inbox now  i want own custom template  with mail . i have using trying for simple layout own

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyLayout";
}

<h2>MyLayout</h2>
```

in my contact us page

i have added this layout like this

```
@model Inspinia_MVC5.Models.MailModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

    @layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml";

}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.summernote').summernote();
        if ('@ViewBag.Message' == 'Sent') {
            alert('Mail has been sent successfully');
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.summernote').summernote();

        });

    });
</script>


<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <div class="ibox-content mailbox-content">
                    <div class="file-manager">
                        <div class="row">
                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-primary compose-mail" href="@Url.Action("ContactUs", "ContactUs")">Compose Mail</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 animated fadeInRight">
            <div class="mail-box-header">

                <h2>
                    Compse mail
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mail-box">

                @using (@Html.BeginForm("ContactUs", "ContactUs", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <div class="mail-body">

                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="get">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">To:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10"> <input type="text" name="To" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email Here"></div>
                            </div>
                            <br />

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10"> <input type="text" name="Subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Subject Here"></div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <br />

                            @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject)*@

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Attachment:</label>

                                <input type="file" name="fileUploader" />
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <div class="mail-text h-200">
                            <div class="summernote">


                                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 840px; height: 139px;" })

                                <br />
                                <br />

                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mail-body text-right tooltip-demo">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary()
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" value="Send" />


                        </div>

                    </div>
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/summernoteStyles")
@Scripts.Render("~/plugins/summernote")
}
```

after Running the code i am getting Error Like this

```
The layout page "= "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml";" could not be found at the following path: "~/Views/ContactUs/= "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml";"
```

please Any one tell how to send own template with mail to inbox

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
@model Inspinia_MVC5.Models.MailModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml";

}
```